# printf("%x", -1<<1); --> Printing fffffffe instead of -2

Tags: c

In this statement the left shift operator produces the value -2 decimal value ... while we are to print it out in an hexadecimal value it should be again -2  ... but the compiler prints fffffffe . What am i missing here?

Comment: `%x` takes an `unsigned int`, it cannot possibly print a negative number.

Comment: `... in an hexadecimal value it should be again -2` Uh... In 2's complement machines (all modern CPUs), -2 is indeed 0xfffffffe.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is with format specifier.
try `printf("%d", -1<<1);` instead.
More about format specifiers here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-c/

Answer (score -1):

Please use:
printf("%d" , -1 << 1);